# Using existing Python packages in VSCode and SSH

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ssh

I installed VSCode and its remote SSH and Python extensions.

I connected to a remote server, let's say by `ssh user_name@ip_address`.

Now, in the remote server, the path the folder with the Python packages I installed long time ago is: `/home/user_name/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`.

How do I use them when I create a Python script in VSCode and, for example, try to `import numpy as np`?

Comment: Using packages installed for different Python runtime is not a good thing to do.

Comment: Use a better IDE or preferably a text editor

Comment: @user234461 text editor preffered over an actual IDE? xD

Comment: Are you asking how to set the interpreter to python3.7 or do you have a preferred interpreter say python 3.11 and want to use the 3.7 packages?

Comment: The interpreter is set to 3.7. But in a Python script, I cannot import the libraries...

Answer (score 1):

Press [control]+[shift]+[P] and type `Python: Select Interpreter`. Click the option that shows up and select the correct interpreter. Then your default environment should use that interpreter and all packages installed for it.

Comment: Changing interpreter is not really what OP asked for, and it certainly isn't this trivial over SSH.

Comment: @matszwecja Then what do you think OP asked for? OP wanted to use packages from the remote Python interpreter and the easiest way to do that is to connect to the remote Python runtime. I use a similar setup with WSL which doesn't involve SSH but still works the same way in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `"python": "path/to/python3.7"` in `launch.json` then use debug mode.